# Parse If-Modified-Since Header (node.js)

Tags: node.js, date, http-headers, if-modified-since

I am trying to implement sending a 304 header for performance in a server hosting program I am writing, but I do not know how to parse the date of the If-Modified-Since header. I also would like to know how to find out if the If-Modified-Since date is older/newer than another date that I have in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To parse the date, use `new Date(datestring)` or `Date.parse(datestring)`. To see if a date is newer or older than another date, use the greater than (>) and less than (<) operators.

Answer (score 6):

Just in case if someone comes across...

- To parse date from `"Last-Modified"` you can use [Date](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) constructor that takes a date string.
- You can also use [Date.parse](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp), which returns number of milliseconds since epoch (for invalid dates it returns `NaN`).
- To print back date in format suitable for `"Last-Modified"` or `"If-Modified-Since"` header you can use Date's [toUTCString()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toutcstring.asp) method.

```js
var date = new Date("Wed, 17 May 2017 04:44:36 GMT");
var ms = Date.parse("Wed, 17 May 2017 04:44:36 GMT");
console.log('parsed date: ', date);
console.log('parsed date ms: ', ms);
console.log('If-Modified-Since: '+date.toUTCString());
```